# How do I import bash variables in R? (Rstudio server)

Tags: r

Let's say I have environment variables in my bash profile that I want to use in R. How would I call those in? For example:

```
export MYSQL_USER='bob'
export MYSQL_PWD='secret'
```

I tried using `Sys.getenv("MYSQL_USER")`, but it just returns a blank.

Comment: How are you running R?

Comment: I'm running RStudio on a server, and logging in through the browser.

Comment: Maybe `system()` with `intern = TRUE`?

Comment: @joran tried system('echo $MYSQL_USER',intern=TRUE), doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Except for platform differences, I believe that works. (Works just fine for me.) Try restarting R first.

Comment: system('$PATH') works

Comment: @Fernando Yes, that works for "default" system variables, but not the ones I have exported in my bash profile. Try it yourself and let me know if you find otherwise.

Comment: @joran You were able to define MYSQL_USER='bob' in your bash profile and call it in from R?

Comment: ......yes. On OS X though.

Comment: Our server is CentOS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running through `rstudio server`, your Bash startup files are not sourced upon starting your `rstudio` instance. See this [reference](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Startup.html) to see which file is sourced. On RStudio Server the global startup file is found at `R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site` by default.